# OpenCV locating centroid gives erros on PiCam

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, webcam

I have a code which locates the centroid of an object placed in front of a camera. I ran the code on my Raspberry Pi where I am using a PiCam for the project, the `cv2.moments()` function's output object,has all values 0. The relevant part of the code is this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera import PiCamera 
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640,480)
camera.framerate = 16
camera.rotation=180
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640,480))

for f in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture,format='bgr',use_video_port=True):  
    # ret, orig_frame = video.read()
    orig_frame = f.array
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(orig_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    low_red = np.array([100, 100, 100])
    up_red = np.array([255, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_red, up_red)
    edges = cv2.Canny(mask, 100, 200)
    bit = cv2.bitwise_or(orig_frame, orig_frame, mask= mask)

    contours, _ ,heirarchy= cv2.findContours(frame1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    setpoint = 315
    stop1 = 250
    stop2 = 370



    for c in contours:

       M = cv2.moments(c)
       print(M) #OUTPUT HAS ALL VALUES 0
       # cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]) 
       # cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
```

The output of the `print(M)` statement is:

```
{'m20': 0.0, 'mu20': 0.0, 'nu30': 0.0, 'm03': 0.0, 'm10': 0.0, 'mu03': 0.0, 'nu02': 0.0, 'm11': 0.0, 'm21': 0.0, 'mu21': 0.0, 'mu02': 0.0, 'mu30': 0.0, 'm12': 0.0, 'm01': 0.0, 'm00': 0.0, 'nu20': 0.0, 'nu03': 0.0, 'nu21': 0.0, 'nu11': 0.0, 'm02': 0.0, 'nu12': 0.0, 'mu11': 0.0, 'mu12': 0.0, 'm30': 0.0}
```

As you can see, all values are 0

However, if I run the same code on my laptop which uses its webcam, the code runs error free and the output of the `print(M)` statement is an object with non-zero values.

This is the code on my local machine:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def make_custom(x, y):
    video.set(3, x)
    video.set(4, y)

make_custom(800, 800) 
while True:
    ret, orig_frame = video.read()



    #frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(orig_frame, (5, 5), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(orig_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)   
    low_red = np.array([100, 100, 100])
    up_red = np.array([255, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_red, up_red)

    frame1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (5, 5), 1)
    edges = cv2.Canny(mask, 100, 200)
    bit = cv2.bitwise_or(orig_frame, orig_frame, mask= mask)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(frame1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)       
    for c in contours:
   # calculate moments for each contour
       M = cv2.moments(c)
       print(M)
```

I am using Python 3.6 on both the machines

What am I doing wrong, and how do I correct it?

Comment: Which version of OpenCV are you using? Note the difference in function return signature on `findContours()` between your two code sets. The signature for `findContours()` has changed a number of times on OpenCV (slightly annoying) so be sure to check the docs for the exact version you are using.

Comment: You'll see on 3.X that the *image* is the first result returned, not the contours, and the contours should be the second result (which you're assigning to the throwaway `_`). https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.8/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a

Comment: Ok,so I checked, and my Pi has openCV 3.4.4 and my laptop has 4.0.0, I'll update cv on the Pi